# reading from a textfile line by line | C++

Tags: c++, file, path, filesystems

i am searching the internet a while now but cant find a solution thats working for me. or i am just dumb. 
I have 12 lines in a .txt file and i want to read those line by line, one after another. starting with 1,2...12. 
my .txt file looks like this:

```
ITEM1     (string)
ITEM2     (string)
ITEM3     (string)
ITEM4     (string)
ITEM5     (string)
ITEM6     (string)
ITEM7     (string)
ITEM8     (string)
ITEM9     (string)
ITEM10    (string)
1         (INT)
NATHAN    (string)
```

whats written in brackets is not written in the file. its just the way it was saved from the program. i wanna read the file and store the text in the variables. The ITEM1-ITEM10 are from an array called inventory[10].
The number '1' is just a marker and goes in the variable 'int gameposition'. The name 'NATHAN' goes in a String 'string charactername'.

File path is:

```
C:\apoadventure\savegame.txt
```

i know that this type of saving savegame information isnt very clever but im new to this and im just trying and learning.

Answer (score 0):

My InputFile.txt

```
Apple 1
Mango 2
Banana 3
Grape 4
```

My main body

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("InputFile.txt");
    std::string str[4];
    for (int i = 0; std::getline(file, str[i]);i++) 
    {
        std::cout << str[i] << "\n";
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Now in the above code i am inputting the data from the .txt file line by line by using the **getline()** function.

This is my output

```
Apple 1
Mango 2
Banana 3
Grape 4
```

Hope this helped you out in how to input data from a file line by line :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have a line based format, so read it with `getline`. Anything that isn't a string can be converted from the string just read (e.g. `stoi` in the code below)

```
string inventory[10], charactername, work;
int gameposition;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    getline(file, inventory[i]);
getline(file, work);
gameposition = stoi(work);
getline(file, charactername);
```

**UPDATE**

```
cout << "Gameposition: " + gameposition << endl;
cout << "Your character: " + selectedChar << endl;
```

should be

```
cout << "Gameposition: " << gameposition << endl;
cout << "Your character: " << selectedChar << endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

This part is working so far.

txt file contains:

```
    ITEM1
    ITEM2
    ITEM3
    ITEM4
    ITEM5
    ITEM6
    ITEM7
    ITEM8
    ITEM9
    ITEM10
    0
    NATHAN
```

```
string savedinv[10], charactername, work;
    int gameposition;
    ifstream file;
    file.open("C:/apoadventure/savegame.txt");
    cout << "Inventory loaded:\n";
    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i) {
        getline(file, savedinv[i]);
        cout << savedinv[i] << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    getline(file, work);
    gameposition = stoi(work);
    getline(file, charactername);
    selectedChar = charactername;
    file.close();

    //handling information
    //inventory + gameposition + selectedChar
    inventory[0] = savedinv[0];
    inventory[1] = savedinv[1];
    inventory[2] = savedinv[2];
    inventory[3] = savedinv[3];
    inventory[4] = savedinv[4];
    inventory[5] = savedinv[5];
    inventory[6] = savedinv[6];
    inventory[7] = savedinv[7];
    inventory[8] = savedinv[8];
    inventory[9] = savedinv[9];
```

But when i try to call the gameposition it gives me NOTHING back.

```
    cout << "Gameposition: " + gameposition << endl;
    cout << "Your character: " + selectedChar << endl;
    cout << "\n";
```

OUTPUT:

```
    ITEM1
    ITEM2
    ITEM3
    ITEM4
    ITEM5
    ITEM6
    ITEM7
    ITEM8
    ITEM9
    ITEM10

    Gameposition:
    Your character: NATHAN
```